# Extracting resource in Argo workflow using "resource" template/step with "get" action and passing to downstream steps?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I'm exploring an easy way to read K8S resources in the Argo workflow. The current documentation is focusing mainly on create/patch with conditions (https://argoproj.github.io/argo/examples/#kubernetes-resources), while I'm curious if it's possible to perform "action: get", extra part of the resource state (or full resource) and pass it downstream as artifact or result output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

`action: get` is now supported: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/246d4f44013b545e963106a9c43e9cee397c55f7/examples/k8s-wait-wf.yaml#L46

**Original answer:**

`action: get` is not a feature available from Argo.

However, it's easy to use `kubectl` from within a Pod and then send the JSON output to an output parameter. This uses a BASH script to send the JSON to the `result` output parameter, but an explicit output parameter or an output artifact are also viable options.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: kubectl-bash-
spec:
  entrypoint: kubectl-example
  templates:
  - name: kubectl-example
    steps:
    - - name: generate
        template: get-workflows
    - - name: print
        template: print-message
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: "{{steps.generate.outputs.result}}"
  - name: get-workflows
    script:
      image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
      command: [bash]
      source: |
        some_workflow=$(kubectl get workflows -n argo | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $1;}')
        kubectl get workflow "$some_workflow" -n argo -ojson
  - name: print-message
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: message
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["echo result was: '{{inputs.parameters.message}}'"]
```

Keep in mind that `kubectl` will run with the permissions of the Workflow's ServiceAccount. Be sure to [submit the Workflow using a ServiceAccount](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/docs/service-accounts.md) which has access to the resource you want to get.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelCrenshaw! I was suspecting this is the only way to go, but couldn't believe such a useful feature was missing. Fair enough! Thumbs up for the example, appreciate it.

Comment: @Oleksandr it is a bit of a bummer. If you find the CLI option too cumbersome for your use case, definitely submit a feature request!

Comment: `action: get` is used in one of the official examples. According to my reading of the source code, all kubectl commands are supported. https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/k8s-wait-wf.yaml#L46

Comment: @JoeBowbeer updated the answer to note this. Thanks!

Comment: @crenshaw-dev One limitation of using `resource` is that only the `delete` action can operate on multiple resources. The `get` action requires a manifest with at least a kind and a name.